# How to display theme and apply css styling to jqx-widget drop down list in angular 4 or 5?

Tags: jquery, css, angular, angular5, jqwidget

I have imported this libraries in angular.json file

```
“input”:”node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/jqx.all”
},
{
“input”:”node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css”
},
{
“input”:”node_modules/jqwidgets-scripts/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.summer.css”
}
```

And intitalize jqx-drop-down in one of html file. Still theme is not been displayed. And if i want to apply css styling to this drop down how it can be done. Please show the necessary code for it.

```
<jqxDropDownList #myDropDownList [theme]='”summer”‘
[width]=”200″ [height]=”50″ (onSelect)=”Select($event)” [source]=”source” [selectedIndex]=”0″ [autoOpen]=”true”>
</jqxDropDownList>
```